# How to use firebase mlkit witn react-native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-mlkit, firebase-machine-learning

I do find info on how to setup basic firebase (like @react-native-firebase/app) for react native, and there is info of how to install ML, but that is old info. The new ones, after 2020, would be ML Kit, or Firebase Machine Learning.
For these new ones, I have not found any info on how to use them with react-native.

There are some links speaking about npm modules like [www.npmjs.com/org/react-native-mlkit](http://www.npmjs.com/org/react-native-mlkit) but that brings nothing but a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about On Device ML (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) you can use this React Native wrapper for ML Kit https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit

To install it you need to install a particular package `@react-native-ml-kit/translate-text` or `@react-native-ml-kit/image-labeling`. Full list you can find in the root of repository.

Comment: Seems there is no "official" way by google at least yet, so good to know about those possibilities. I found also some pointing to cloud vision and related, but it all seems a bit messy as from react-native point of view.